# How do you pass a block parameter to a method taking a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to declare a method that takes a block as a parameter to get executed on dismissal of an alert, so have something like the following. 
But can't hit on the syntax for passing the block parameter to the onDismiss part:

```
- (void) notifyUserOfProblemWithDismissBlock: ( (^)()) block
{
    [UIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle: @"whatever"
                            message: nil
                  cancelButtonTitle: nil
                  otherButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:     NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON_OK", nil)]
                          onDismiss:^(int buttonIndex){
                              block;
                          }
                           onCancel:^ {}];
}
```

Comment: your type for `block`, `(^)()`, is not valid. It needs to have at least a return type. e.g. `void (^)()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the block called 'block' directly to the UIAlertView method, it would need to have the same signature (same return type, numuber and type of methods) as that method expects for its dismissal block. Since it doesn't, you can pass a block that does have the right signature, then in the body of *that* block, call your block. You're almost there. The key you're missing is that the syntax for invoking a block is:

block();

So, do this

```
- (void) notifyUserOfProblemWithDismissBlock:(void(^)(void)) block
{
    [UIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:@"whatever"
                                message:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                      otherButtonTitles:@[NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON_OK", @"BUTTON_OK")]
                              onDismiss:^(int buttonIndex) {
                                  block();
                              }
                               onCancel:^{}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing a compatible block type, then just use its argument name:

```
...
onDismiss:theBlock
...
```

otherwise (**this is the case you enconutered**), wrap it into another block in which you call the one originally passed in as the argument:

```
...
onDismiss:^(int btnIdx) {
    theBlock();
}
...
```

Also, if you're not intending to do anything in a block, as in `onCancel:`, you can just pass `nil` or `NULL` there.